# Упростить код на PHP

Tags: php

Как бы упроситить вот такой код. Слишком много повторов.

```
$ca0 = round((count_active($dbcnx,0)/$total)*100);
$ca1 = round((count_active($dbcnx,1)/$total)*100);
$ca2 = round((count_active($dbcnx,2)/$total)*100);
$ca3 = round((count_active($dbcnx,3)/$total)*100);
$ca4 = round((count_active($dbcnx,4)/$total)*100);
$ca5 = round((count_active($dbcnx,5)/$total)*100);
$ca6 = round((count_active($dbcnx,6)/$total)*100);
$ca99 = round((count_active($dbcnx,99)/$total)*100);
```

Comment: я правильно вас понял, что итерации идут с 0 до 99?

Comment: массив однозначно кашернее. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3494a58c36cf3456ecf58ab1231647a6afe3b378

Comment: @BruAPAHE нет, итерации от 0 до 6, дальше отдельно 99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хранить в переменных изначально плохая идея, лучше не плодить кучу однотипных переменных и хранить данные в массиве

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
   $ca[$i] = round((count_active($dbcnx,$i)/$total)*100);
}
```

Так же посмотрите вот эти функции для обработки массивов на будущее

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php

Comment: дак вот `range` с `array_map` и применили бы

Comment: Научи человека ловить рыбу, и он будет сыть всю жизнь)

Comment: Ну почему $i < 100 -то)) $i < 7. Дальже $i = 99. Я специально не указывал многоточие))

Comment: Просто добавь внутр цикла:

if($i >= 7 && $i <= 100) {
    continue;
}

Answer (score 4):

Можно имя переменной собирать вот таким образом

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
   ${'ca'.$i} = round((count_active($dbcnx,$i)/$total)*100);
}
```

Но если честно, мне думается, надо сделать массив - вам же потом это обрабатывать, всю эту кучу переменных